# how to generate a button in a specific position?

Tags: javascript, button

I have a menu in which the user interacts with it. The menu options are: 
Create button, edit button, delete button. 
I have to make sure that when the user chooses to create a new button, you activate a feature; The user must then provide the coordinates that are used to place the button on the screen. 
Edit button is used to change the position of a button already generated. 
Delete button deletes a button already generated.

```
<html>
<body>

<input type="button" value="create button" onclick="build()">
<input type="button" value="delete button" onclick="delete()">
<input type="button" value="edit button" onclick="edit()">

<script>

var x, y, z, k;

function build()
{

var button =document.createElement('button');
x = prompt("Inserisci posizione TOP");
y = prompt("Inserisci posizione Sinistra");
button.style.right = x;
button.style.left = y;
button.style.width = 50;
button.style.height = 50;
button.setAttribute("value","generated button");
document.body.appendChild(button);

//doesn't function

}

function delete()
{

}

function edit()
{


}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried to use position fixed?

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of issues with your code.

**1.** Use of the reserved word `delete` (rename it to myDelete or something else).

**2.** The element will just sit in the document flow right now. Set .style.position = 'absolute';

**3.** You set the right and left members to be x and y. Change them so that left=x and top=y.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class, like 'built' when the function build() is called. Have this class give a fixed position to the button so it's coordinates will properly be set within the window. If you'd like, wrap the buttons in a div, with a relative position. Then give the 'built' button an absolute class.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .button.built {
        position: fixed;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="button" value="create button" onclick="build()">
    <input type="button" value="delete button" onclick="deleteButton()">
    <input type="button" value="edit button" onclick="edit()">

    <script>

    var x, y, z, k;

    function build()
    {

    var button = document.createElement('button');
    x = prompt("Inserisci posizione TOP");
    y = prompt("Inserisci posizione Sinistra");
    button.style.top = x;
    button.style.left = y;
    button.style.width = 50;
    button.style.height = 50;
    button.setAttribute("value","generated button");
    button.className = button.className + "button built";
    document.body.appendChild(button);

    //doesn't function

    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you even try this code? You covered point #2 that I mentioned, but neglected to take care of #1 and #3.

Comment: @user3344186, just specified a fix earlier to guide you, there is now a working example.

Comment: And as u/enhzflep so kindly suggests, address his 1st point about removing the reserved word.